# C# Casting Generic<B> to Generic<A> where B : A

Tags: c#, generics, type-conversion

I've got two classes, MyClassA and MyClassB. MyClassB inherits from MyClassA. I've written a method with the following signature

```
public void DoSomething(MyGeneric<MyClassA> obj);
```

I've also got the following event handler.

```
public void MyEventHandler(Object source, EventArgs e)
{
   //source is of type MyGeneric<MyClassB>
   DoSomething((MyGeneric<MyClassA>)obj);
}
```

I understand that `MyGeneric<MyClassA>` is not of the same type `MyGeneric<MyClassB>` but since MyClassB is a subclass of MyClassA is there still a way to make this work?

For reference, the exact error message:

> Unable to cast object of type
>   'MSUA.GraphViewer.GraphControls.TreeNode`1[MSUA.GraphViewer.GraphControls.MaterialConfigControl]'
>   to type
>   'MSUA.GraphViewer.GraphControls.TreeNode`1[MSUA.GraphViewer.PopulatableControl]'.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is type contravariance in generics.

Even though `B` is a subtype of `A`,
**`Generic<B>` is not a subtype of `Generic<A>`,**
so you can't cast `Generic<B>` to `Generic<A>`.

Check: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517.aspx for more details.

You can overload `DoSomething()` to `DoSomething(Generic<B>)`, this method can then convert `Generic<B>` to `Generic<A>` and call `DoSomething(Generic<A>)`.

Comment: Well basically converting Generic<B> to Generic<A> would mean, Generic<(A)Generic<B>.B>() but that won't help, will it, since B was cast to A but is still also B. Anyway, great answer, you're absolutely right, gonna be hard though to work around this.

Comment: He can also try changeing the `MyGeneric<A>` to the interface type like `IEnumerable<A>`. Will this work?

Comment: @Roy T you could try an `implicit operator` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z5z9kes2.aspx

Comment: @StuperUser, I'll take a look at the implicit operator. Also important to note is that in VS2010 you have the generic contravariance modifier in: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd469484(VS.100).aspx that allows contravariance, but unfortunately I'm still stuck at 2008/.NET 3.5

Comment: @StuperUser Interfaces will work, see the sample. `class Base { }
class Derived : Base { }
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var b = (IEnumerable<Base>)new List<Derived>();
    }
}`

Comment: Oh cool @oleskii. I misunderstood how interfaces work with contravariance. Have deleted my specious comment.

Comment: @oleksii: That works because `IEnumerable<out T>` is covariant in `T` (see my answer below). Sadly that is only available in .NET 4.0. In .NET 3.5 that code will not compile.

Answer (score 5):

If your generic class `MyGeneric<T>` can implement an `interface` which is covariant in `T` then you could do the following:

1. Define an interface covariant in `T`:

   ```
   public interface IMyGeneric<out T>
   {
       T Foo();
   }
   ```

   This means that the generic type `T` can only be  an output type (can not be part of a method signature defined in the interface.)
2. Make your class `MyGeneric<T>` implement `IMyGeneric<out T>`.
3. Now through the `interface`, which is covariant in `T`, the following code is valid:

   ```
   IMyGeneric<MyClassB> classBGeneric = new MyGeneric<MyClassB>();
   IMyGeneric<MyClassA> classAGeneric = classBGeneric;
   ```

   So in your case, you could write the following:

   ```
   public void MyEventHandler(object source, EventArgs e)
   {
       DoSomething((IMyGeneric<MyClassA>)source); //IMyGeneric<MyClassB> is implicitly convertible to IMyGeneric<MyClassA>
   }
   ```

**EDIT**: Just read in comments that you are working with .NET 3.5, so sadly this won't work in your case. I'll leave the answer in case it is of any use to somebody else. Sorry, I missed that important piece of information.

Comment: still this is a good answer, it would solve my issue in 2010, and I forgot to mention in the actual question that I'm stuck at 2008/.NET.3.5 :)

Answer (score 1):

<s>Most</s> Some generic classes have a cast< T > function which does it for you. If it doesn't exist you could try to create your own.

Comment: Most? I *am not* aware that "most generic classes have a Cast<T> function." I *am* aware there is a `Cast<T>` extension method defined *for sequences* that attempts to cast each item in a sequence. Your answer seems to imply it's part of the generic pattern almost by default.